# I try to update Bootstrap in Visual Studio 2022 but I get an error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-5

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")   // here I got error

@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

This is the error I get:

[image: this ERROR will I receive]

I need a solution to update Bootstrap.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Dude, why post a question if you're not checking for an answer? :p

Answer (score 0):

Locate the App_Start folder in your project, then open BundleConfig.cs and edit the ~/bundles/bootstrap to reference the updated Bootstrap files instead of your original references.

You're getting the null reference because it's still pointing towards the old Bootstrap files which was removed during the update.